# mkdir php права доступа

Tags: php

какие права на папку нужны для mkdir("имя", права); что бы с браузера никто не мог открыть файлы в этой папке но можно было php кодом создавать файлы в папку
и брать из них контент (из файлов)

Comment: Те, кто «с браузера» действуют через веб-сервер – смотрите, под каким юзером и группой у вас работает процесс веб-сервера (nginx или apache). 

«php код» работает либо совместно с веб-сервером, и тогда их не разделить правами дискового доступа, либо отдельным процессом php-fpm который может быть под тем же, или под другим юзером. Если под другим – можно решить вашу задачу правами.

Comment: Какой у вас веб сервер? Как работает php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в .htaccess прописать надо Deny from all

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, правами на папку вашу задачу не решить.

Обычно файлы, которые из браузера не должны быть доступны, просто держат вне папок, доступных из веба.

Например, популярный движок WordPress позволяет держать «секретный» файл с конфигами как в корне сайта, так и на один уровень выше, чтобы обезопасить его содержание:

```
/var/www/site/
  wpconfig.php  <- это «секретный» файл
  public/       <- это корень веб-сайта
    index.php
    и прочие файлы
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант в .htaccess  прописать запрет просмотра всех папок

```
Options All -Indexes
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#
# Set default safe rights to web folder
#

SITENAME=${2%/}
DIR=${1%/}

# files
STATUS="Setting 644 for files $DIR"
echo -n $STATUS
find $DIR -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
echo -e "\r$STATUS [OK]"

# dirs
STATUS='Setting 755 for directories'
echo -n $STATUS
find $DIR -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
echo -e "\r$STATUS [OK]"

#user and group
DATE=`date +%S%N`
FILE="$DATE.php"

cd $DIR
mkdir $DATE
echo "<?php\n" > $DIR/$DATE/$FILE
echo "echo exec('id');" >> $DIR/$DATE/$FILE

USER=`curl -s "$SITENAME/$DATE/$FILE" | cut -d ' '  -f 1 | cut -d '(' -f 2 | cut -d ')' -f 1`

GROUP=`curl -s "$SITENAME/$DATE/$FILE" | cut -d ' '  -f 2 | cut -d '(' -f 2 | cut -d ')' -f 1`

rm -f $DIR/$DATE/$FILE
rmdir $DIR/$DATE

STATUS="Setting owner of directory to user: $USER and group: $GROUP ";
echo -n $STATUS
chown -R $USER:$GROUP $DIR
echo -e "\r$STATUS [OK]\n\n"
```

Писал скрипт для себя. Первым аргументом путь к корневой директории, вторым веб-путь (домен)

Пример:

```
sh rights.sh /var/www/site http://site.ru
```

Что делает скрипт?

1. Устанавливает права на папки 755
2. Устанавливает права на файлы 644
3. Определяет пользователя и группу под которым скрипт запускается
   апачем и назначает его владельцем файлов и папок

После этого все скрипты будут работать нормально и прав должно хватать.
Если проблемы именно с **mkdir**, то возможно вы пытаетесь создать несколько директорий рекурсивно, а это возможно только если передается специальный параметр.

Пример:

```
mkdir ('/path/to/recursive/dir', 0755, true)
```